# OCR with Xamarin.Form + Azure Cognitive Service

Tags: xamarin.forms, ocr

I am developing on Windows 10 with Visual Studo 2019.
I'm trying to do OCR with Xamarin.Form+Azure Cognitive Service.
I was able to set up Azure.
The project is being tested on Android (actual device 9.0) with Xamarin.

Form. After taking a picture, I use its Path.

```
public ReadImage()
{
    var file="/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20210122_1709.jpg";
    var visionClient = Authenticate(SubscriptionKey, EndPoint);

    var ocrResult1 = visionClient.RecognizePrintedTextAsync(true, "file:/" + file);
    var ocrResult2 = visionClient.RecognizePrintedTextAsync(true, "file:" + file);
    var ocrResult3 = visionClient.RecognizePrintedTextAsync(true, "file://" + file);
    var ocrResult4 = visionClient.RecognizePrintedTextAsync(true, "file:///" + file);
}
```

The ocr.Result is returned with Status=Faulted.
The error message is as follows

One or more errors occurred. (Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.)

file://mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20210122_1709.jpg
file:/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20210122_1709.jpg
file:///mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20210122_1709.jpg
file:////mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20210122_1709.jpg

What should I do with the path to Recognize in OCR?

[NuGet solutions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idAMW.jpg)
I used RecognizePrintedTextInStreamAsync.
But Error.

```
    var ocrResult5 = visionClient.RecognizePrintedTextInStreamAsync(true, new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));
    //One or more errors occurred. (Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.)

    var ocrResult6 = visionClient.RecognizePrintedTextInStreamAsync(true, new FileStream("file:"+file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));
    //Could not find a part of the path "/file:/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20210126_1050.jpg".

    var ocrResult7 = visionClient.RecognizePrintedTextInStreamAsync(true, new FileStream(file.TrimStart('/'), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));
    //One or more errors occurred. (Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.)

    var ocrResult8 = visionClient.RecognizePrintedTextInStreamAsync(true, new FileStream("file:/"+file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));
    //Could not find a part of the path "/file:/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20210126_105535.jpg".

    var ocrResult9 = visionClient.RecognizePrintedTextInStreamAsync(true, new FileStream("file://"+file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));
   //Could not find a part of the path "/file:/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20210126_105535.jpg".
```

Add var stream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read); result Debug image.
[StearmReader is success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVgP0.jpg)

Comment: RecognizePrintedTextAsync appears to expect the url of an image, so you **first** need to upload the image to a publicly accessible url.  Or you could use RecognizePrintedTextInStreamAsync, which allows you to pass a stream for the image.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
I tried RecognizePrintedTextInStreamASync.
However, all of them resulted in errors as shown in 5-9 that I added.
Please tell me how to specify the path.

Comment: "/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20210122_1709.jpg" is a file path

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
In the first line
var file="/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20210122_1709.jpg";
so it should be
I understand that "/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20210122_1709.jpg" is the file path.

However, when I pass that file as the second argument of RecognizePrintedTextAsync, I get an Invalid URI error.
Passing that file to the second argument of RecognizePrintedTextInStreamAsync will result in an Invalid URI error.
Therefore, I would like to know how to convert the file to a URI.

Comment: can you just do `var stream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);`?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. That is a very nice idea.
 var stream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
 var ocrResult10 = await visionClient.RecognizePrintedTextInStreamAsync( true, stream);
 I divided it into two lines like this and executed it. Then the stream was readable, as shown in the additional figure attached. I logged in to Azure and confirmed that it was correct. https://username. cognitiveservices.azure.com/